# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shareplum'

Tags: python, airflow, shareplum

I got below error nevertheless package itself has been installed and can be seen by doing `pip list`. What issue might it be?

**Error:**

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/sharepoint_test.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/sharepoint_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    from shareplum import Site, Office365
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shareplum'
```

**Package is installed:**

```
airflow@airflowhost:/opt/airflow$ pip list | grep Sha
SharePlum                                0.5.1
```

Code which throws error:

```
import csv
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from shareplum import Site, Office365
from shareplum.site import Version
import json, os

USERNAME = ''
PASSWORD = ''
SHAREPOINT_URL = ''
SHAREPOINT_SITE = ''
SHAREPOINT_DOC = ''

class SharePoint:
    def auth(self):
        self.authcookie = Office365(SHAREPOINT_URL, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD).GetCookies()
        self.site = Site(SHAREPOINT_SITE, version=Version.v365, authcookie=self.authcookie)

        return self.site


    def connect_folder(self, folder_name):
        self.auth_site = self.auth()
        self.sharepoint_dir = '\\'.join([SHAREPOINT_DOC, folder_name])
        self.folder = self.auth_site.Folder(self.sharepoint_dir)
        return self.folder

    def download_file(self, file_name, folder_name):
        self._folder = self.connect_folder(folder_name)
        return self._folder.get_file(file_name)

def process_file():
    file_name = 'sample.pdf'
    folder_name = 'Reference'
    file  = SharePoint().download_file(file_name, folder_name)

with DAG("sharepoint_test",
         schedule_interval=None,
         start_date=days_ago(2)) as dag:

    process_file = PythonOperator(task_id="process-file",
                                  python_callable=process_file)

    process_file
```

Comment: Not sure here but should your import statement be from SharePlum (i.e. with capitals?)

Comment: do not think so

Comment: How are you running airflow (docker, k8s, Cloud Composer etc)? If Docker what image are you using?

Comment: @DanielT docker file, but on another computer I am running on Kubernetes. In not cases I got very same error. I've checked pip list and share plum package is installed therefore I do not understand why I am getting this error, unless something is wrong in python code itself (from packages) ?

Comment: Whose Docker image are you using? ([bitnami](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-airflow) for example?). Depending on the image being used we can look at how third party packages should be installed to the environment. What you've done should work so I'm assuming the Docker image needs a bit of config to install global packages. (it might be using a virtual environment inside the image for example)

Comment: @DanielT but what global packages u mean since shaerplum is installed

Comment: shareplum might be installed globally inside the container, but airflow itself could be using a virtual environment inside the container. If shareplum isn't installed to this environment, you will get this error. Without knowing the image you're using it's impossible to tell however.

Comment: @DanielT I pasted it here as it was too much for main post: tinyurl.com/yam7643y

Comment: You're using the official airflow Docker image. Have you followed the instructions on [extending the image](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html)? You'll need to follow the instructions on adding [pypi packages](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#adding-new-pypi-packages-individually) to install shareplum. If re-building the image is undesirable, you could use [Bitnami's image](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/airflow#how-to-use-this-image) (I use this myself in a production environment). This lets you specify a requirements.txt.

Comment: @DanielT if we talk about extending the image where should I put this dockerfile on behalf of docker-compose.yaml which I use currently?

Comment: I had a similar issue. I was trying to install shareplum on a different version of python. It worked as i changed the python interpreter to it's default version.